# JWT Token auth in Micro service architecture (Java - Spring)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices

I am trying to create a event based, decoupled microservice based on Java Spring. I have so far created two services:

1. Movie Service (for getting and filtering movies from db)
2. User service (for Auth)
3. Common (for shared entities)

So far I was able to implement a login which returns a JWT token and a filter that will validate the JWT token based on secret, however my problem is that I want to use this token in Movie Service and other API's as well, but werent able to find solution. So far only thought i have in mind is seperating JWT filter in another project (or in Common project) but I do not know if that is good idea.

Is there anyone that can help me with this matter? Also my another question is that is it OK to use common project?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out this [link](https://medium.com/javarevisited/spring-boot-authorization-creating-an-authorization-server-for-your-microservices-50a3aefd6ce8)

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using Spring Webflux

Cache Token

```
private Mono<String> tokenRequest = getToken().cache(Duration.ofMinutes(30));
```

Token code

```
private Mono<String> getToken() {
        var keys = "clientid:clientsecret";
        String encodedClientData = null;
        encodedClientData = Base64Utils.encodeToString(keys.getBytes());
        return WebClient.builder().build().post().uri(Token URL)
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedClientData)
                .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("grant_type", "client_credentials")).retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class).map(tokenResponse -> tokenResponse.get("access_token").textValue());
}
```

API call

```
public Mono<String> obtainSecuredResource() {
        return tokenRequest.flatMap(token -> getResource(token));
}

private Mono<String> getResource(String authToken) {
        return WebClient.builder().build().get()
                .uri(API URL)
                .headers(h -> h.setBearerAuth(authToken)).exchangeToMono(response -> {
                    
                    if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                        return response.bodyToMono(String.class);
                    } else if (response.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
                        return Mono.just("Error response");
                    }
                    else if (response.statusCode().is5xxServerError()) {
                        return Mono.just("");
                    }else {
                        return response.createException().flatMap(Mono::error);
                    }
                });
    }
```